# Можно ли как-то узнать, из-за чего на смартфоне подлагивает анимация?

Tags: javascript, css, pagespeed

Решил протестировать сайт на смартфоне - одна из анимаций подлагивает(спустя мгновение после начала анимации). Сначала подумал, что плохая оптимизация - пожертвовал частью стилей и js-кода, чтобы проверить, действительно ли дело в оптимизации - эффекта ноль, лаги точно такие же. Вопрос: могу ли я как-то понять, что именно вызывает лаги? Или придётся вручную всё перебирать? Нет, виновата явно не сама конкретная анимация, которая лагает. Если оставить только её - лагов нет.

Answer (score 2):

Уже начал проверять вручную. И нашёл виновника - filter: blur. Уж не знаю, почему он такой затратный по ресурсам смартфона оказался.